# What's the difference between the svmtrain and fitcsvm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I know that `fitcsvm` is a new command in matlab new version and in the latest document say that `svmtrain` will be removed. Are the two commands the same? Actually I notice that they are different in result in my recent work. Can anyone help me with this strange problem?

Answer (score 2):

from [fitcsvm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html):

`fitcsvm and svmtrain use, among other algorithms, SMO for optimization. The software implements SMO differently between the two functions, but numerical studies show that there is sensible agreement in the results.`

from Wikipedia [Sequential minimal optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization):

`SMO is an iterative algorithm for solving the optimization problem ...`

Answer (score 2):

According to my experiments, I found that the two functions are different. fitcsvm takes the empirical distribution into consideration, the distribution is related to the number of positive samples and negatives in the default situation. However, svmtrain just take this distribution as [0.5 0.5], and one can think there's no prior knowledge.
Further, it may be with the data whether they have been standardization, to get more about this, just find the related document about SVM.